# Searching for a point on the local coordinate system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems

**First variant (1):**

- global and local coordinate system are the same
- I know the coordinates of the center of the element
- finding the coordinates for A and B is:

*Code for obj:*

```
RectTransform rectTransform = obj.GetComponent(typeof(RectTransform)) as RectTransform;
if (rectTransform == null) rectTransform = obj.AddComponent(typeof(RectTransform)) as RectTransform;
Vector3 point = new Vector3(obj.transform.position.x (+-) rectTransform.transform.localScale.x / 2, obj.transform.position.y, obj.transform.position.z)
```

**Now the question is how to do it for the second variant? (2)**

`Position` and `LocalScale` works on the global system, so I have no way to look for a point using the coordinate system assigned to an element

**I would like to add that this object can be freely rotated and scaled on all axes in space**

[image]

Comment: Not Unity, but if you have the transform to convert from local space to global space, you can invert it to get a transform from global space to local space. Once you have that, you can convert coordinates into a common coordinate system. How you do this with Unity, or if I understood what you're saying properly, I don't know, so apologies if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very well explained. Its not very clear what your problem is and what do you want to achieve.
Regarding your 1st point: global and local coordinate system are the same, this is not correct. It might happen that if the object is in the global system origin, points in one or other system have the same values, but this does not mean the coordinates system are the same.

You have all the tools available in the unity's transform class to manipulate positions and rotations in their respective coordinate systems accordingly.
[Local position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html), [local rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html), [global position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html), and [global rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html).

The transform class has the functions also to tranform points, directions and vectors from local to global space and viceversa, so that you can manipulate data in the code in the coordinate system you need when the information is not be within the tranform class, so that you can provide that as an argument.
From world space to local space, you need to check [InverseTransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html), [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html), and [InverseTransformVector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformVector.html).
And from local to world space [TransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html), [TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html), [TransformVector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformVector.html).

Everything in the [Transform class documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) which is very good.

I think you need to check in any of these cases apply to your problem, and if not, try to edit your question to leave clear what the problem is, and why the transform functions of unity do not apply to your case.